# Android 4.4 full-screen mode for Progress Dialog

Tags: android, android-progressbar, android-4.4-kitkat

I want my app to run in full-screen mode on devices running Android 4.4.

I have set `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION` for my view and it runs in full-screen.

The problem is when I show a `ProgressDialog`. Then the app exits full-screen mode and the navigation buttons at the bottom are visible agin.

Is it possible for an app to remain in full-screen mode when a progress dialog is shown?

Comment: Immersive mode gets removed as soon as the window loses focus and I'm unable to find any workaround. Were you able to find any answer to this?

Answer (score 3):

There's a little workaround I found on this topic: [How to maintain the Immersive Mode in Dialogs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22794049/how-to-maintain-the-immersive-mode-in-dialogs) thanks to [Beaver6813](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1019728/beaver6813)'s answer (here is the sample code project on [GitHub](https://github.com/samcleaver/immersivetest)).

So basically, what I did to use this solution on my ProgressDialog is:

- Add two variables to my MainActivity class:

  ```
  private ProgressDialog pDialog;    
  private Activity context;
  ```
- Add the following code in my `onCreate` method:

  ```
  context = this;    
  getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(    
      View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE    
      | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION    
      | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN    
      | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar   
      | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar    
      | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
  ```
- Add the following code where I start my `ProgressDialog` method:

  ```
  pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);    
  pDialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, 
      WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);    
  pDialog.show();    
  pDialog.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
      context.getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility());    
  pDialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
  ```

That should do the trick!