# How to maintain Immersive mood with custom dialogfragment?

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I am trying to use Immersive mode for full screen view. In this screen I am trying to show a `dialog fragment` with two `EditText` fields. I tried this solution [How to maintain the Immersive Mode in Dialogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22794049/how-to-maintain-the-immersive-mode-in-dialogs). This solution only works when I didn't use any `EditText` inside `DialogFragment`. My problem is when I use EditText fields and write something using `softkeyboard` and close the `Dialog`, `Immersive` mode don't come back again. How can I solve the problem? Can anyone help me for this issue?