# Prevent StatusBar from showing when using AlertDialog.Builder

Tags: android, android-fragments

In the `XML` of my `MainActivity`, I have programmed it so that **it uses** a theme with `NoActionBar` and therefore there is no action bar displayed. However, whenever I want to display a dialog, I call one of my `DialogFragments` that uses an `AlertDialog.Builder` to create the dialog. When I show the dialog from within the main activity, it shows the dialog with the `ActionBar`. **When I then close the dialog box**, **the action bar remains**.

**QUESTION**: How do I have consistency and hide the action bar when the fragment disappears, or have it not display in the first place?

I have tried creating a custom style and then wrapping that in a `ContextThemeWrapper` to no avail.

`getActionBar().hide()` and `getSupportActionBar().hide()` returns null both on the main activity and the fragment.

`myDialog.getDialog()` in the MainActivity (before `.show()` is called) returns `null`.

The code I have used to create the `AlertDialog.Builder` is within `DialogFragment`'s `onCreateDialog`:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
     builder.setTitle(R.string.delete_confirmation)
            .setItems(fileSequence, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {
                    File loadedFile = fileFullArray.get(which);

                    boolean deleted = loadedFile.delete();

                    if (deleted)
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "File deleted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                        {
                            // User cancelled the dialog
                        }
                    }
            );
    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
    return builder.create();
```

**EDIT:**

Came back to this 4 months later and the fix was adding the following line in the Dialog's `onCreate()`:

`this.getActivity().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);`

The Fragment's `onCreate()` was overwriting was written in the `MainActivity`. Cheers.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot and the code involving the AlertDialog.Builder?

Comment: Make a look If you are using a custom layout on your Dialog!

Comment: @EugenPechanec updated

Comment: I cannot see the **ActionBar** man... Are you interested in to hide **StatusBar**? If you're, just use     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
 on your activity's theme, hope it helps! Or if you 're looking for doing in Java, just add getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

Comment: I declare a theme like that already in my app's AndroidManifest.xml. The StatusBar (my apologies, I mixed up the terminology) only appears when clicking the Dialog. I presume this is a problem with the dialog rather than the Activity itself?

Comment: **It isn't**, You could get rid of your status bar with the code from the code I said before. You are looking for do **FULLSCREEN**, which one doesn't show statusbar and toolbar

Comment: I have added another screenshot. The statusbar is not displayed by default. It only appears when I click the delete button. I hope this is more clear.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For API Level 17 and up, see [gprathour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45690109/4624156)'s answer.

For API Level 16 and lower, the following line needed to be added to my Dialog's `onCreate()`

```
this.getActivity().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score 4):

### Latest Working Example

The accepted answer works only for API Level 16 or lower.
In newer versions, for `AlertDialog` do the following:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
    alert.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
} else {
    View decorView = alert.getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a resource from the android official docs. So basically, for android version 4.1 and higher, use this code:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide the status bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
// Remember that you should never show the action bar if the
// status bar is hidden, so hide that too if necessary.
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

**PS:** Source [Link to official android doc](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html#41)

Answer (score 0):

Calling this method I've created at the Dialog's `onCreate()` fully resolved the problem of status bar show or show/hide.

```
private void hideStatusBar(Window window) {
    window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use on style.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    </style>
</resources>
```

It makes your activity without your `ActionBar`!

**UPDATED:**

I have some code, It should works on you!

```
ab = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this,
                    AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK);

            ab.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                }
            });

            ab.setTitle(R.string.welcome_title);
            ab.setMessage(R.string.message);
            ab.create().show();
```

**UPDATED2:**

here some code on `Java`

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

and some on `XML`

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
</activity>
```

Hope it be helpful!

Comment: After reading the first line of the question ("I have programmed it so that it uses a theme with NoActionBar") your answer seems really redundant.

Comment: If you make a screenshot of your alerdialog, it could be helpful for me

Comment: I believe it is common practice to read the question you're attempting to answer.

Comment: Sorry, if he update with more information, I could give a better answer, I read whole question, but forget the first line... My mistake...