# Popup window makes notification bar visible on fullscreen activity in android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-popupwindow

I have a fullscreen activity and setting it to full screen by the following code

```
private void setFullScreenFocus() {
    getWindow().getDecorView()
            .setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
}
```

I have implemented a pop up window dialog but when it is shown it makes the status bar and nav bar visible. How to avoid that?

Below is the popupwindow code

```
PopupWindow seasonEpisodePopUpWindow;
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) anchorView.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (seasonEpisodeView == null)
        seasonEpisodeView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.player_seasons_episode_list, null);
if (!seasonEpisodePopUpWindow.isShowing()) {
            seasonEpisodePopUpWindow.showAtLocation(anchorView, Gravity.BOTTOM, viewLocation[0], height);
            appCMSPlayVideoFragment.setPreviousNextVisibility(false);
        }
```

Comment: You can check this link for your code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36554599/prevent-statusbar-from-showing-when-using-alertdialog-builder

Comment: are you sending this activity object while creating the dialog? like `new AlertDialog(this)` or something?

Comment: @RahulKumar popupwindown is not alertdialog

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem has been occurring only on Android 5.0 and only when a popup window was a full screen window. I found a following workaround, instead of:

```
mPopupWindow.setWidth(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
mPopupWindow.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

i wrote:

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
mPopupWindow.setWidth(displayMetrics.widthPixels);
mPopupWindow.setHeight(displayMetrics.heightPixels);
```

and it surprisingly worked.