# bottomSheetDialogFragment full screen

Tags: android, material-design, bottom-sheet, material-components-android, material-components

What I'm trying to achieve is something like Instagram in-app web browser, used when you click an ad:

[image: Instagram web browser]

what I did, is I used a WebView bottomSheetDialogFragment, and I override `onCreateDialog` to get the full screen like this :

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog=(BottomSheetDialog)super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    bottomSheetDialog.setOnShowListener(dialog -> {
        BottomSheetDialog dialogc = (BottomSheetDialog) dialog;
        FrameLayout bottomSheet =  dialogc .findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
        BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet).setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
        //BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet).setSkipCollapsed(true);
        //BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet).setHideable(true);
    });
    return bottomSheetDialog;
}
```

here is the result I get :

[image: web browser]

my  question is, how can I get the full screen effect, or how can achieve something like instagram browser?

ps: I tried first  chrome custom tabs, but I couldn't add it inside dialog fragment.

Thank you.

Comment: Right solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33644326/hiding-status-bar-while-showing-alert-dialog-android#answer-40744282

Answer (score 89, accepted):

In your custom [`BottomSheetDialogFragment`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/BottomSheetDialogFragment.md) you can use something like:

```
  @NonNull @Override public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
      @Override public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
        BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = (BottomSheetDialog) dialogInterface;
        setupFullHeight(bottomSheetDialog);
      }
    });
    return  dialog;
  }


  private void setupFullHeight(BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog) {
    FrameLayout bottomSheet = (FrameLayout) bottomSheetDialog.findViewById(R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
    BottomSheetBehavior behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = bottomSheet.getLayoutParams();

    int windowHeight = getWindowHeight();
    if (layoutParams != null) {
      layoutParams.height = windowHeight;
    }
    bottomSheet.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
  }

  private int getWindowHeight() {
    // Calculate window height for fullscreen use
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((Activity) getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    return displayMetrics.heightPixels;
  }
```

Comment: Isn't working for me. Only gets me around 70% up the screen. Any suggestions?

Comment: @CodeWiget might be because the content of your bottom sheet isnt large enough to stretch through the whole screen

Comment: If you need the full height without statusbar you should call:

(context as Activity).findViewById<View>(Window.ID_ANDROID_CONTENT).height

Comment: it's kinda a fixed size for its content view.

Comment: Those who cannot access `android.support.design.R.id.design_bottom_sheet` can try the following: `com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet`

Comment: @AsafK what can I do to achieve the same if my content isn't large enough to stretch all the available screen? It's a list and it might be empty

Comment: hey can you help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66533461/issue-in-creating-a-transparent-activity-on-top-of-another-activity

Comment: This one worked for me

Comment: Another workaround to make some crappy simple Android component customizable. I really wonder what those masterminds behind this perfect feature thought when they decided to create such component?! "Make it as unusable as possible?!"

Comment: @Krusty Solution for android components is to not use them at all. Simple as that

Answer (score 65):

Sorry for the late answer but in your custom BottomSheetDialogFragment you can set `match_parent` to layout params of bottom sheet view like this:

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    val dialog = BottomSheetDialog(requireContext(), theme)
    dialog.setOnShowListener {

        val bottomSheetDialog = it as BottomSheetDialog
        val parentLayout =
            bottomSheetDialog.findViewById<View>(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet)
        parentLayout?.let { it ->
            val behaviour = BottomSheetBehavior.from(it)
            setupFullHeight(it)
            behaviour.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
        }
    }
    return dialog
}

private fun setupFullHeight(bottomSheet: View) {
    val layoutParams = bottomSheet.layoutParams
    layoutParams.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    bottomSheet.layoutParams = layoutParams
}
```

Setting height to `match_parent` helps your dialog to be drawn above the inset of Navigation bar

Answer (score 35):

Proposed solutions are based on using an internal `id`, since it is not on purpose exposed it could change without warning.

My solution set the layout height to the `FrameLayout` but in a more abstract way, so if it changes it shouldn't break, even if the `ViewGroup` type change.

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    val sheetContainer = requireView().parent as? ViewGroup ?: return
    sheetContainer.layoutParams.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
}
```

If you take a look at the `BottomSheetDialog` the `private View wrapInBottomSheet` method you will see this happens to guarantee the sheet behavior. Some extra debugging, allowed me to figure the fragment `View` is the direct child from the `FrameLayout` everybody is finding by id.

In this way, you don't need to rely on the ID. I'm using `onStart` because is defined at the point when the fragment is ready for interactions, so all should be ready.

And if you need it full height from the start (most probably)

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    return BottomSheetDialog(requireContext(), theme).apply {
        behavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
        behavior.peekHeight = //your harcoded or dimen height
    }
}
```

Comment: If anyone has the same problem I do where the modal doesn't return to full screen when released halfway. `onCreateDialog`, set the peek to `peekHeight = resources.displayMetrics.heightPixels`

Answer (score 24):

You can do it by setting `peekHeight` of `BottomSheetBehavior` to be equal to `Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels`:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog=(BottomSheetDialog)super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    bottomSheetDialog.setOnShowListener(dialog -> {
        BottomSheetDialog dialogc = (BottomSheetDialog) dialog;
        // When using AndroidX the resource can be found at com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet
        FrameLayout bottomSheet =  dialogc.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.design_bottom_sheet);

        BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
        bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels);
        bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
    });
    return bottomSheetDialog;
}
```

Comment: this was the better solution for me, the accepted answer offsets the bottom of the dialog and makes kt partially not visible

Comment: When using AndroidX the resource can be found at com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet

Comment: Simply use R.id.design_bottom_sheet, no need to specify complete package in my case.

Answer (score 17):

You can do it by changing the state of your dialog to `STATE_EXPANDED`:

```
BottomSheetDialog dialog = (BottomSheetDialog) getDialog();
dialog.getBehavior().setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
```

Kotlin:

```
val dialog = dialog as BottomSheetDialog
dialog.behavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
```

Comment: it takes only about half width

Comment: Works Fine Thanks .

Comment: very simple and working.. i like this answer...

Answer (score 14):

Here's how you do it in kotlin,

```kotlin
val dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)
dialog.setOnShowListener {
    val bottomSheetDialog = it as BottomSheetDialog
    val parentLayout = bottomSheetDialog.findViewById<View>(
        com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet
    )
    parentLayout?.let { bottomSheet ->
        val behaviour = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet)
        val layoutParams = bottomSheet.layoutParams
        layoutParams.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        bottomSheet.layoutParams = layoutParams
        behaviour.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
    }
}
return dialog
```

Answer (score 11):

The best way to to this is through XML

Customize default BottomSheet by overriding it's attributes, for example in styles.xml

```
<style name="Widget.MyApp.BottomSheet.Modal" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="behavior_skipCollapsed">true</item>
    <item name="behavior_fitToContents">true</item>
    <item name="behavior_peekHeight">1000dp</item> // yep, that helped to skip collapsed state at initial
    <item name="behavior_hideable">true</item>
</style>
```

Go inside Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomSheet.Modal to see what settings you can modify.

Then create custom theme inherited from Theme.Design.BottomSheetDialog and set that you want to override bottom sheet's style with you own. Also can be placed in styles.xml

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp.BottomSheetDialog" parent="Theme.Design.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/Widget.MyApp.BottomSheet.Modal</item>
</style>
```

And the last, define your new created theme for bottom sheet dialog in your Activity's theme or Application's theme, which placed in themes.xml(hope you follow Google's recommendations about packaging styles&themes)

```
<style name="Base.Theme.MyApp" parent="Base.Theme.Root">
    ... too many other things
    <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/Theme.MyApp.BottomSheetDialog</item>
```

Comment: Great solution, Works as ehpected.

Answer (score 6):

I used such way:

- add a view with "android:layout_height="match_parent" into root layout
- when dialog is shown (or before this) update of BottomSheetBehavior with "isFitToContents = false" and "state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED".

Code:

```
override fun onShow(dialog: DialogInterface?) {
    BottomSheetBehavior.from(binding?.root?.parent as View).apply {
        isFitToContents = false
        state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
    }
}
```

Xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/fragment_cities_root_background">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <!-- other views -->

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout >
```

Answer (score 6):

just add below line of code

```
bottomSheetDialog.getBehavior().setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
```

and layout should be inside `NestedScrollView`

Answer (score 4):

try this in your custom BottomSheetDialogFragment:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        setupFullHeight()

    }

    private fun setupFullHeight() {
        val bottomSheetDialog = dialog as BottomSheetDialog
        val behavior = bottomSheetDialog.behavior
        behavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Full screen + customizable rounded corners:
[image]

Define the following extension -

```
fun Dialog.setFullScreen(
    @Px cornerRadius: Int = <some value>,
    skipCollapsed: Boolean = true
) {
    check(this is BottomSheetDialog) {
        "Dialog must be a BottomSheetBottomSheetDialog."
    }

    lifecycleScope.launch {
        whenStarted {
            val bottomSheetLayout = findViewById<ViewGroup>(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet)  ?: return@whenStarted
            with(bottomSheetLayout) {
                updateLayoutParams {
                    height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                }
                clipToOutline = true
                outlineProvider = object : ViewOutlineProvider() {
                    override fun getOutline(view: View, outline: Outline) {
                        outline.setRoundRect(
                            0,
                            0,
                            view.width,
                            view.height + cornerRadius,
                            cornerRadius.toFloat()
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
            behavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
            behavior.skipCollapsed = skipCollapsed
        }
    }
}
```

Then just do this from your `BottomSheetDialogFragment`:

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState).apply { setFullScreen() }
}
```

Or you can create an abstract class like this:

```
abstract class FullScreenBottomSheetDialogFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState).apply { setFullScreen() }
    }
}
```

A couple of notes:

- you can use the `setFullScreenExtension` for regular `BottomSheetDialog` and not just for its `BottomSheetDialogFragment` version
- the solution is not setting any custom dialog listeners under the hood (like `setOnShowListener`) so you can still use them in your dialogs if you need to, i.e. they won't be overridden by the `setFullScreen` extension

Comment: What a great answer! Works as expected :chefs_kiss:

Answer (score 1):

A pretty answer from official [Material-Components](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/BottomSheetDialog.java) github

All you have to do is some magic - add this to you app theme/style

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="enableEdgeToEdge">true</item>
```

**Fullscreen mode**

> On API 21 and above the BottomSheet will be rendered fullscreen (edge
> to edge) if the navigationBar is transparent, and enableEdgeToEdge is
> true. It can automatically add insets if any of
> paddingBottomSystemWindowInsets, paddingLeftSystemWindowInsets,
> paddingRightSystemWindowInsets, or paddingTopSystemWindowInsets are
> set to true in the style, either by updating the style passed to the
> constructor, or by updating the default style specified by the
> bottomSheetDialogTheme attribute in your theme.
>
> BottomSheetDialog will also add padding to the top when the
> BottomSheet slides under the status bar to prevent content from being
> drawn underneath it.

Comment: it takes only about half width

Answer (score 0):

In my Case using kotlin

```
   private fun exerciseDialog() {
                val dialogBinding: DialogExerciseBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                    LayoutInflater.from(requireContext()), R.layout.dialog_exercise, null, false
                )
                val mDialog = BottomSheetDialog(requireContext())
                mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
                mDialog.setContentView(dialogBinding.root)
                mDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)
        
                val parentLayout =
                    mDialog.findViewById<View>(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet)
                parentLayout?.let { it_ ->
                    val behaviour = BottomSheetBehavior.from(it_)
                    setupFullHeight(it_)
                    behaviour.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
                }
        
                mDialog.show()
        
            }
        
            private fun setupFullHeight(bottomSheet: View) {
                val layoutParams = bottomSheet.layoutParams
                layoutParams.height = (getScreenHeight(requireActivity()) * .90).toInt()
                bottomSheet.layoutParams = layoutParams
            }

  fun getScreenHeight(activity: Activity): Int {
        val outMetrics = DisplayMetrics()

        return if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            val display = activity.display
            display?.getRealMetrics(outMetrics)
            outMetrics.heightPixels
        } else {
            @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
            val display = activity.windowManager.defaultDisplay
            @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
            display.getMetrics(outMetrics)

            outMetrics.heightPixels
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in onViewCreated of BottomSheetDialogFragment

```
dialog.setOnShowListener { dialog ->
    val d = dialog as BottomSheetDialog
    val bottomSheet = d.findViewById<View>(R.id.design_bottom_sheet) as FrameLayout
    val bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet)
    bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**this worked perfectly for me:**

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    (dialog as? BottomSheetDialog)?.behavior?.state = 
    BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated (@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onViewCreated (view, savedInstanceState);

BottomSheetBehavior<View> bottomSheetBehavior BottomSheetBehavior.from ((View) view.getParent());

bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE EXPANDED);

assert layout!=null;

layout.setMinimum Height (Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels);

}
```

This worked for me , 4lines of code and it's done when the bottom sheet fragment is created .

Comment: Please do not post [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: Downvoted, Same reason as @JanVítek

Comment: What is `layout`? There is no such property