# how to show website in Bottonsheetdialog android studio

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-bottomsheetdialog

how to show a web page with webview in BottonSheetDialog !
like this

[click here for see example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egYVE.png)

Comment: Have you tried anything before asking?

Comment: just google it , i was able to found the solution by searching how to show website in Bottonsheetdialog  , if you have a problem with your code paste it here so we can help you , check this [bottomSheetDialogFragment full screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58065771/bottomsheetdialogfragment-full-screen)

Comment: yeah just error !!! i check that but no help me

Comment: It's hard to help with an error without seeing the original error message. Please edit your post to include the exact wording of any error messages, including the full [stack trace](/a/23353174) of any exceptions, if applicable, as well as which line of code the stack trace points to. Please see [ask] and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do you have to create a class that extends `BottomSheetDialogFragment`, you have to create a layout that contains a `webview`, then call `oncreateview()` method where you inflate layout and set up the `webview` with its reference from the layout, then in your activity show the `bottomsheetdialog`

*First create a layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webview"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

- Secondly create a class that extends BottomSheetDialogFragment

```
//Extend Your class with BottomSheetDialogFragment
public class WebViewBottomSheet extends BottomSheetDialogFragment{

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        
        //Inflate Your layout which contains the webView
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.weblayout,container,false);

        WebView webView = view.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.loadUrl("Put your URL here");
        return view;
    }
}
```

- And finally just show your BottomSheet in your activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        
        //Here you show your BottomSheetDialog
        WebViewBottomSheet webViewBottomSheet = new WebViewBottomSheet();
        webViewBottomSheet.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"Show Bottom Sheet");
    }
}
```

PS: Don't forget to add the design library to your project