# How to make BottomSheetDialog full screen?

Tags: android, kotlin, bottom-sheet, android-bottomsheetdialog, bottomsheetdialogfragment

I have this simple BottomSheetDialog and i wanted to make it full screen:

```
class RegistrationDialog : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {


    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        var view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_registration, container, false)
        return view

    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bottomSheetDialogFragment full screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58065771/bottomsheetdialogfragment-full-screen)

Comment: Should this work only if a i'm using a webview?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try with the following code.

```
//call from activity using below line
val bottomSheetDialog = TestDialogFragment();
 bottomSheetDialog.show(supportFragmentManager, "Dialog");

class TestDialogFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
private lateinit var binding: FragmentAddDocumentDialogBinding

override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    val dialog = BottomSheetDialog(requireContext(), theme)
    dialog.setOnShowListener {

        val bottomSheetDialog = it as BottomSheetDialog
        val parentLayout =
            bottomSheetDialog.findViewById<View>(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet)
        parentLayout?.let { it ->
            val behaviour = BottomSheetBehavior.from(it)
            setupFullHeight(it)
            behaviour.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
        }
    }
    return dialog
}

private fun setupFullHeight(bottomSheet: View) {
    val layoutParams = bottomSheet.layoutParams
    layoutParams.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    bottomSheet.layoutParams = layoutParams
}


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    binding = FragmentAddDocumentDialogBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but how can i call this BottomSheet in another activity?