# Hide StatusBar when displaying BottomSheetDialog

Tags: java, android, android-bottomsheetdialog

I have a full screen `Activity`, here is all the related code on how I make it fullscreen:

---

Manifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name=".Player"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen.player" />
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen.player" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Activity `onCreate`

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

---

I then display a `BottomSheetDialog`, as shown below:

```
bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(this);
bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(dialogView);
bottomSheetDialog.show();
```

---

The problem I have is when I show the `BottomSheetDialog`, the `StatusBar` gets shown as well.

I have noticed that the `StatusBar` is hidden when in-app purchase dialog gets displayed and it looks to me like it's a `BottomSheetDialog`.

How can I not show the `StatusBar` when I'm displaying a `BottomSheetDialog`?

Comment: Hi.. I just tried and it works just fine for me. Let me post what I have tried..

Comment: @sanjeev Ok thanks, I'm waiting for your response.

Comment: Right solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33644326/hiding-status-bar-while-showing-alert-dialog-android#answer-40744282

Answer (score 1):

I have applied theme to my **BottomSheetDialog** and it works perfectly for me.

This is my `v21/styles.xml`:

**P.S:** I have used this for `windowContentTransitions` in my theme hence not necessary to use.

```
<style name="AppTheme.RoundedBottomDialog">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
        <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/AppBottomSheetDialogTheme</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppBottomSheetDialogTheme"
        parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/AppModalStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppModalStyle"
        parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/white_bottom_sheet</item>
    </style>
```

This is my `styles.xml`:

```
 <style name="AppTheme.RoundedBottomDialog">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
        <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/AppBottomSheetDialogTheme</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppBottomSheetDialogTheme"
        parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/AppModalStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppModalStyle"
        parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/white_bottom_sheet</item>
    </style>
```

And I have applied it to `<activity>` like,

```
<activity
            android:name=".SomeActivity"
            android:configChanges="locale|orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.RoundedBottomDialog"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden" />
```

Comment: I will try this and get back to you. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I have tried this, but the statusbar is still shown.

Comment: I did not use this `<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>` or declare anything in `onCreate`..

Comment: I removed it but still no luck

Comment: @HB try with different device

Comment: @HB. can you try it with `BottomSheetBehavior` or `BottomSheetDialogFragment`?

Answer (score 1):

Might be late to answer this question. For others reference, the `StatusBar` will not be shown when the following flags are set before the return of the `onCreateView` method:

```
dialog?.window?.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
```

This is applied to when showing a modal bottom sheet dialog with `BottomSheetDialogFragment`. Tested on a device running on Android 8.0.

For persistent bottom sheets with `BottomSheetBehavior`, just apply a fullscreen theme to the `Activity` or set the `android:windowFullscreen` attribute to true on the `Activity`'s theme will do.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by call hideStatusBar after dialog show() method. I use kotlin style.

```
    fun hideStatusBar() {
    val uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY or
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
    window?.decorView?.systemUiVisibility = uiOptions
}
```