# Showing BottomSheetDialogFragment in immersive mode

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I want to show a BottomSheetDialogFragment in immersive mode. Originally the nav and status bar would show when the dialog is displayed, but I can get that sorted with the code below. However, when the dialog is shown, or dismissed, the nav bar flashes for a split second. Is there a way I can show the BottomSheetDialogFragment fully immersive, without the nav bar flashing on show and dismiss?

```
abstract class ImmersiveBottomSheetDialogFragment<T : ViewDataBinding> : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    protected lateinit var binding: T

    private val systemUiVisibility: Int = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY)

    fun showImmersive(
        fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
        tag: String,
        tapOutsideEnabled: Boolean = false
    ) {
        show(fragmentManager, tag)
        fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions()
        dialog?.let { dialog ->
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(tapOutsideEnabled)
            dialog.window?.let { window ->
                window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = systemUiVisibility
                window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this:

```
override fun setupDialog(dialog: Dialog?, style: Int) {
    super.setupDialog(dialog, style)
    dialog?.window?.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE)
}
```

([from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22794049/how-do-i-maintain-the-immersive-mode-in-dialogs?rq=1))

Also add this:

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    var viewParent = view
    while (viewParent is View) {
        viewParent.fitsSystemWindows = false
        viewParent.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener { _, insets -> insets }
        viewParent = viewParent.parent as View?
    }
}
```

What does this do? `DialogFragment#onActivityCreated()` calls `Dialog#setContentView()`, which wraps the Dialog's view in a private 'wrapInBottomSheet'.  In order to set the proper flags of those wrapper views, we want to set the flags *after* they are wrapped, e.g. after super.onActivityCreated()

Also watch [this talk](https://speakerdeck.com/chrisbanes/becoming-a-master-window-fitter-droidcon-london-2017) for info on `fitsSystemWindows` and window insets.