# Android App exits Fullscreen when showing a Dialog on a Fullscreen Activity

Tags: android, dialog, fullscreen, android-fullscreen

Per request, I'm trying to make an Android application fullscreen. I've followed [Enable fullscreen mode](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive), but when showing a dialog, the navigation menu (home button, back button, etc...) displays again while the dialog is shown. Is there a way to disable this?

I made a sample app, based on the Fullscreen Activity template, and I observe the same behavior:
[image: Fullscreen Activity]
[image: Fullscreen Dialog]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dialog window is focusable by default and focusable windows leads to the exit from fullscreen mode.

For workaround you can try to set `FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE` flag to your dialogs as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23207365) but note that system dialogs such as ANR will still lead to an exit.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I adapted the solution slightly for a base dialog class. It's too long to post in a comment, so I'll post it as another answer, but I'll mark your answer as accepted. :)

Answer (score 1):

Sharing my solution, based on the answer in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23207365) [@ceribadev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2900125/ceribadev) shared:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

    // Here's the magic..
    try {
        // Set the dialog to not focusable (makes navigation ignore us adding the window)
        dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);

        // Show the dialog!
        dialog.setOnShowListener(dialogInterface -> {
            // Set the dialog to immersive
            dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(dialog.getOwnerActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility());

            // Clear the not focusable flag from the window
            dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return dialog;
}
```